# How to transfer Preview signatures on Mojave?

Tags: preview, mojave, signature

Following the out-of-date [Can I export my signature from Preview on one Mac and import it on another?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74950/can-i-export-my-signature-from-preview-on-one-mac-and-import-it-on-another) - 
On Mojave no signature data appears in the folder ~/Library/Containers/com/apple.Preview/Data/Library/Preferences

Where are the signatures saved now and how exactly can they be transferred to a new Mac such that they are usable in Preview? (including any required decryption keys/settings)

Comment: I am also looking for this answer. Anyone?