# Import signature from image file in Preview

Tags: macos, pdf, preview

I'd like to sign pdfs using my signature. Unfortunately, Preview seems to require that you have a trackpad or a camera to do it. I have a Mac Mini, which has neither.

I do have my signature as a jpeg. In Acrobat on Windows, I could just import it and it worked. How do I do that in Preview?

Answer (score 2):

Signatures are stored in the keychain.  If you can create a signature on another machine this thread may be of use
[Can I export my signature from Preview on one Mac and import it on another?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74950/can-i-export-my-signature-from-preview-on-one-mac-and-import-it-on-another)

Comment: This is helpful to know, but not a good solution if one doesn't already have another keychain containing the image to be imported.

Answer (score 1):

Extending existing solutions:

- Either grab a mac that has a cam, or plugin an apple Display with a cam (older iMac monitor mode or Studio Display). An alternative is to visit an apple store, take your mini with you, ask to demo a Studio display.
- Print the old signed document on paper, white out on the parts where the signature overlapped the form, then hold it up to the camera, wait for it to be recognized.
- Create signature dropdown
- At the top go to the second tab (Camera)
- Hold up paper until the rendering it creates looks good
- Export via keychain
- Airdrop it where you need
- Done

Comment: Can you explain how you connect the camera here to the Mac mini in the question with an edit to the answer?

Comment: @bmkie I missed the mac mini constraint, will update

Comment: Nice work, I didn’t see another question to host the simpler answer or I would have linked.