# Import new signature without using isight

Tags: webcam, digital-signature

My isight doesn't works, i use another mac for create my digital signature.

How can I import and set my signature on my mac ?

where storage it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Send an email to yourself with the signature you made on the other
   mac from the other mac.
2. Open the email on the mac with the broken iSight.
3. Select the signature and copy (cmd + c) it.
4. Go to Mail/preferences/signatures and create a new signature.
5. Paste (cmd + v) in the signature box.

Is this what you mean?

Comment: no.This Signature
http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Signature-from-a-Built-in-iSight-in-Mac-OS-X-Lion

Comment: So you don't want to use the signature with Mail?
In that case have a look at this answer http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/49458/71490

Comment: Thanks again, i haven't this `com.apple.Preview.signatures.plist`

Comment: can you try copying the com.apple.Preview.signatures.plist from the mac WITH isight to the mac WITHOUT isight?